# How to populate List datatype in the list

Tags: python, list

I want to populate the datatype of the list element into the List.

```
A=['X',123,'Xcw-123','ABC-er']
B=['string','int','string','string']
```

I tried to create this using type like.

```
A=[type(i) for i in A]
```

But I am getting list like:

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>,<class 'str'>]
```

Anyone suggest me another approach for this.

Comment: `type(i).__name__` (where the name of the type is `str` not `string`)

Comment: @Klaus D i tried with __name__ but i am getting ['type', 'type', 'type'] as expected.

Comment: If you affect the result of your list comprehension to A THEN apply the other method you'll obtain what you got.

Comment: That would be the result of `type.__name__` not of `type(i).__name__`.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to accomplish ultimately? Why do you want those strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
AA = [type(i).__name__ for i in A]
print(AA)
```

Output

```
['string', 'int', 'string', 'string']
```

Comment: I'm getting `['str', 'int', 'str', 'str']` :/

Comment: @TrebledJ I am using `Python 3.8.2` and the above result is showing in my IDE

Comment: @toRex It's not possible. The name of type string is `'str'` not `'string'`.

Comment: @toRex use AA = ['string' if i=='str' else i for i in AA ] to convert str to string

Comment: Thanks, Everyone for Really a very helpful solution

Comment: @Rishav nice try `'string' if i=='str' `